# Resizing 2D arrays to a different size (e.,g. reduction or comression)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, compression

What is the best way to resize a 2D array (the array has a thermal data contents values between 20 to 30) from size 173X151 to size 146X121 without losing too much information.

I understand it is possible to reduce the size of images with some function(images of intensity values 0 to 255) but my understanding that these functions are for images and not other types of arrays.

Is there a function for reducing the size for any type of array? something like compressing the 2D array to different sizes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

n-dimensional arrays can be many things, aside from being an image.
one example would be a geo-spatial representation that would consolidate (roll-up_ whenever you zoom out and drill down whenever you zoom in.

array resizing technique should rely on the context of such resize takes place, and hence there is no best answer. 
But typically resizing arrays or tensors is by consolidation whenever you reduce number of entries, and by interpolation whenever you increase them